# New attribute created in admin side is not showing in storefront UI in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have created a new attribute (which is a multi select dropdown) and added to attribute set. When I edit or create a product in admin, that newly created attribute is found there and I can select the values and save.

So It supposed to show in user front end side. But thats not showing there in the product detail page. It still shows only color and size.

In the product attribute settings in admin panel I have updated the settings as ,

- "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" to "Yes",
- "Used in Product Listing" to "Yes",
- "Scope" to "Global" and
- Diabled Cache.

Is there any settings which I have to accomplish the same?

Comment: I have also same issue. :)

Comment: have you add attribute in default attribute set?

Comment: Now I added my new attribute into default attribute set. But didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-index database: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`. Remember that a new attribute 'usually' shows under more info tab.

[image]

If you made some custom layout or template, please revert back to Magento default.

Comment: No, I want to display it among the size and color attributes where user can select the value.

Comment: As I understand, you want to use this attribute for configurable product?

Comment: My new attribute is delivery options. Two type of delivery, standard and rush. Rush delivery need 100$ etc. So I need to display that two delivery options in a dropdown in the product detail page. So user can select desired delivery option.

Comment: @ArunSS you can create the custom option - Desired delivery option.

Answer (score 1):

Use in Quick Search yes

Use in Advanced Search yes

Comparable on Front-end yes

Use In Layered Navigation yes

Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price
Use In Search Results Layered Navigation yes

Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price
Use for Promo Rule Conditions yes

Position

Position of attribute in layered navigation block
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend yes

Visible on Product View Page on Front-end yes

Used in Product Listing yes

Depends on design theme
Used for Sorting in Product Listing yes

Depends on design theme
Visible on Pricefalls Datafeed for Custom Field Mapping yes